In Libre Office, what is the most compatible file format to export work as?
Using Libre Office Calc - 24.2.2.2
As the title asks, what type of file are we best to use for exporting a complex spreadsheet, that will be sent to clients allover, and be opened on various type of spreadsheet software?
I sent out a spreadsheet, in the .ods format. It went well, but some could not open drop downs on excel on their phones. There were a few compatibility issues i had not expected!
